# Problemas formulario PHP

Tags: php, html, formularios

Tengo un formulario en una misma pagina, y el problema que tengo es el siguiente si el doy a actualizar me sigue mandando el email constantemente, si hago un header y redirecciono pierdo el mensaje de enviado con exito. necesito alguna solucion.

Y otro problema que quiero solucionar al pulsar el boton enviar del formulario me lleva al principio de la web y yo quiero que se mantenga tal como esta en la posicion de donde esta el formulario y no me desplaze hasta arriba de la pagina y tenga que volver de nuevo a bajar para ver el formulario y los mensajes de exito o errores. Este es el codigo.

```
<?php 

  $errores = '';
  $enviado = '';


  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $area = $_POST['area'];

    if (!empty($nombre)) {
      $nombre = trim($nombre);
      $nombre = filter_var($nombre, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
      $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un nombre <br />';
    }
    if (!empty($email)) {
      $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un correo valido <br />';
      }
    } else {
       $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un correo <br />';
    }

    if(!empty($area)){
      $area = htmlspecialchars($area);
      $area = trim($area);
      $area = stripcslashes($area);
    } else {
      $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa el mensaje <br />';
    }

    if(!$errores){
      $enviar_a = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com';
      $asunto = 'Correo enviado desde mi pagina';
      $mensaje_preparado = "De: $nombre \n";
      $mensaje_preparado .= "Correo: $email \n";
      $mensaje_preparado .= "Mensaje ". $area;

      mail($enviar_a, $asunto, $mensaje_preparado);
      $enviado = true;
    }

}

 require 'index.php';



 ?>
```

y este el formulario html

```
<div class="row">

  <?php if (!empty($errores)): ?>
    <div class="error">
      <?php echo $errores; ?>    
    </div>
    <?php elseif($enviado): ?>
       <div class="success">
         <p>Enviado con extio</p>  
       </div>
  <?php endif ?>   

  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
        <input type="text" class="validate" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php if(!$enviado && isset($nombre)) echo $nombre ?>">
        <label for="icon_prefix nombre" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Introduce tu nombre </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
        <input type="email" class="validate" id="email" name="email" value="<?php if(!$enviado && isset($email)) echo $email ?>">
        <label for="icon_prefix1 email">Introduzca su email</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
        <textarea class="materialize-textarea" id="area" name="area"><?php if(!$enviado && isset($area)) echo $area ?></textarea>
        <label for="icon_prefix2 area">Escriba su mensaje</label>
      </div>
      <div class="center-align">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light deep-purple lighten-2 yellow-text text-accent-1" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Enviar
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que después de que se envía la información por POST, si recargas la página se reenviarán y por lo tanto volverá a entrar al IF, de hecho te debe aparecer un alert diciendo que si quieres reenviar los datos.

Una posible solución es que dejes independiente el archivo que tiene el formulario Html y el archivo que procesa el envío de la info por POST, y que envíes los mensajes por GET.

Por ejemplo:

**form.php**

```
$error = isset( $_GET['error']) ? $_GET['error'] : '';
$exito = isset( $_GET['exito']) ? $_GET('exito') : '';

// PHP7 equivale a: $error = isset( $_GET['error']) ?? '';

<form action="procesar_form.php" method="post">

// Si hubo un error, te imprimirá el mensaje, sino, imprimirá cadena vacía, igual con exito ...
echo $error;
echo $exito;
//el resto de tu formulario....
```

Lo que hace este código es que primero evalúa si existe una variable get llamada error y otra llamada exito (que son las que enviarás, ahorita muestro cómo), si existen sus valores serán asignados para posteriormente imprimirlos.

Caso contrario, $error y $exito se les asigna cadena vacía. Si te fijas, el formulario enviará los datos a **procesar_form.php**:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  // Asignación y validación de datos. Digamos que el nombre está vacío...

  // Rediriges a form.php con una variable GET llamada error que es la que cachará
  if ( !empty($nombre)) {
    header('location: form.php?error=nombre vacio');
  }

  // Resto del código si pasa la validación, enviar email, etc. 
}
```

Otro modo que puede ser más eficaz de validar datos sería algo como

```
if ( empty( $nombre) or empty( $email) or empty( $mensaje) )
{
  header('location: form.php?error=debes llenar todos los datos');
}
```

Y para el mensaje de éxito, sería así:

```
// Ya no necesitas evaluar $errores porque si los hay, redirecciona y no continua el flujo

$enviar_a = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com';
$asunto = 'Correo enviado desde mi pagina';
$mensaje_preparado = "De: $nombre \n";
$mensaje_preparado .= "Correo: $email \n";
$mensaje_preparado .= "Mensaje ". $area;

// Mejor aquí validar si se envia el correo
if ( mail($enviar_a, $asunto, $mensaje_preparado))
   header('location: form.php?exito=Enviado correctamente :) ');
else
   header('location: form.php?error=Huno un error al enviar el correo :( ');
```

De ese modo aunque recargues la página de formulario no pasará nada a menos que esté una variable GET se seguirá imprimiendo.

**Nota:** Aquí doy por hecho que los archivos form.php y procesar_form.php están en la misma carpeta/directorio.

Comment: `GET[]` !== `$_GET[]`

Comment: Cierto, lo corrijo. Gracias por la observación.